# Fork of geth - activate mining ONLY when there's transaction(s) that've come from a certain wallet/address. How?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, mining, forks, full-node

This may be a fork of geth, or any other node client, or a tweak in its functionality:

I want to be able to activate mining process only when, and if, there have come transaction(s) from a certain wallet(s)/address(es). Let's call them "targeted transactions". After such a block has been mined, switch to the "idle" mode where it waits for other targeted transactions. Once another one arrives -- scramble to mine it all the while grabbing others, non-targeted transactions.

In other words: mine targeted transactions ASAP. If it requires including other non-targeted transactions in a block - so be it.

How to do it?